# troubles creating an empty dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create an empty data.frame in R in order to populate it later. the structure I am trying to create is simple: it just has a column with some names (strings) and another where each entry is an integers vector of (potentially) different length

ex:

john | 1,2

mark | 4,5,6

andy | 9

I would like to create the structure and to fill it in later since I am reading data from another dataframe...I could do it using a loop but I was wondering if there was a faster and more elegant solution...I tried

```
data<-data.frame(people = names,counts = replicate(20,list(c(numeric(0)))))
```

where names is a list of 20 elements.

I also tried

```
rep(list(c(numeric(0))),20)
```

but I always get the same error

```
arguments imply differing number of rows: 20, 0
```

I hope you find the question interesting and not too stupid since I am new to R...I used to be a matlab fan LOL

thank you

Comment: Is it important to have a `data.frame` structure? If each individual is going to have a different number of elements, I think a list would fit better.

Comment: thanks @R18 it would be a good solution as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an empty data frame :

```
data <- data.frame(names = character(0), counts = I(list()), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Create a 20 rows data frame filled with <s>`NA`s</s> *(edit)* empty strings `""` and a list of empty numeric vectors:

```
data <- data.frame(names = character(20), counts = I(replicate(20, numeric(0), simplify = FALSE)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

*edit:* if you want `NA`s rather than `""`s, try `rep(NA_character_, 20)` rather than `character(20)`